# JavaFx prevent children from triggering setOnMouseEntered for the parent

Tags: javafx

A pretty simple question, with a simple answer, I hope.

I have a somewhat complex custom Node that extends a Group.

How can I prevent JavaFx from firing `setOnMouseEntered` events for the Group, when a child is hovered?

`setMouseTransparent` hackery doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried to set [pickOnBoundsProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty)? By the way, `setMouseTransparent` will set to the node *and* its children.

Comment: I just tried setPickOnBounds(false/true), but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple test application and the Group didn't get the mouse events:

```
private static final class Foo extends Group {
    Foo() {
        final Rectangle blue = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLUE);
        blue.setLayoutX(50);
        blue.setLayoutY(50);
        blue.setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Entered blue"));

        final Rectangle green = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GREEN);
        green.setLayoutX(250);
        green.setLayoutY(90);
        green.setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Entered green"));

        final Rectangle red = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.RED);
        red.setLayoutX(100);
        red.setLayoutY(200);
        red.setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Entered red"));

        getChildren().addAll(blue, green, red);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final Pane root = new AnchorPane();
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    root.getChildren().add(foo);
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Hover Demo]

This is because the implementation of it mouse picking:

`Node#contains` is implemented as

```
public boolean contains(double localX, double localY) {
    if (containsBounds(localX, localY)) {
        return (isPickOnBounds() || impl_computeContains(localX, localY));
    }
    return false;
}
```

and `impl_computeContains` is defined in Parent which is the superclass of Group

```
protected boolean impl_computeContains(double localX, double localY) {
    final Point2D tempPt = TempState.getInstance().point;
    for (int i=0, max=children.size(); i<max; i++) {
        final Node node = children.get(i);
        tempPt.x = (float)localX;
        tempPt.y = (float)localY;
        try {
            node.parentToLocal(tempPt);
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node.contains(tempPt.x, tempPt.y)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, well I don't see that in your test case you set a listener for the group itself? Did you just not include that bit? Thanks for test anyways. However, I got the behaviour I wanted simply by setting a listener for the rectangle of the group. My nodes are basically rectangles. I don't know what convoluted things I am doing then, if it really should work out of box.

Comment: @user2499946, you can add the line `setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("Entered group"));` in the constrcutor. Even if a listener is set on the group, you don't will get events of the group.